# Array of JLabels in Jpanel not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

So im tearing my hair out at this, I cannot seem to figure out why these JLabels are not drawing to the window.  I keep looking at another project Ive done in the past that also used JLabels inside a JPanel and everything seems right.  Does anyone see where I am messing this up?

```
package lab19_20;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab19_20 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{


    JLabel[] lblBoard = new JLabel[16];
    int[] nums = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8};
    int firstChoice = -1;
    int tries = 0;
    JLabel lblFirst;
    JButton btnGame = new JButton("New Game");
    JLabel lblTries = new JLabel("0");
    JPanel pnlControls = new JPanel();
    JPanel pnlBoard = new JPanel();
    Font lblBoardFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);
    Container content = this.getContentPane();

    public Lab19_20()
    {
        setTitle("The Concentration Game");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        createLabels();
        content.add(pnlBoard, BorderLayout.NORTH);        
        pnlControls.add(btnGame);
        pnlControls.add(lblTries);
        content.add(pnlControls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnGame.addActionListener(this);
    }

    void createLabels()
    {
        pnlBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
        for(int i = 0; i < lblBoard.length; i++)
        {
            lblBoard[i] = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            lblBoard[i].setVisible(true);
            lblBoard[i].setOpaque(true);
            lblBoard[i].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            lblBoard[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblBoard[i].setFont(lblBoardFont);
            lblBoard[i].addMouseListener(this);
            lblBoard[i].setName("" + i);
            pnlBoard.add(lblBoard[i]); 
        }
    }

    void shuffle()
    {
        int num1, num2, tmp = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            num1 = r.nextInt(nums.length);
            num2 = r.nextInt(nums.length);
            tmp = nums[num1];
            nums[num1] = nums[num2];
            nums[num2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        shuffle();
        firstChoice = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lblBoard.length; i++)
            lblBoard[i].setText("");
        tries = 0;
        lblTries.setText("" + tries);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
    {
        JLabel l = (JLabel) me.getSource();
        int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(l.getName());
        if (firstChoice == -1)
        {
            l.setText("" + nums[theNumber]);
            lblFirst = l;
            firstChoice = theNumber;  
        }
        else if (nums[theNumber] != nums[firstChoice])
        {
            l.setText("" + nums[theNumber]);
            pnlBoard.paintImmediately(0,0, pnlBoard.getWidth(), pnlBoard.getHeight());

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException blah){}

            lblFirst.setText("");
            l.setText("");
            lblFirst = null;
            firstChoice = -1;
            tries++;
        }
        else
        {
            l.setText("" + nums[theNumber]);
            firstChoice = -1;
            tries++;
        }

        lblTries.setText("" + tries);

    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Lab19_20 console = new Lab19_20();
    }

    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}   
    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}   
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {} 

}
```

Comment: Start by calling `setVisible(true);` last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick things...

1. Call `setVisible(true);` last, after you have established the basic UI.
2. Use `lblBoard[i].setText("" + i);` instead of (or as well as) `lblBoard[i].setName("" + i);`

Comment: That was it, as soon as I added in setText right after setName it fixed the issue.  Care to elaborate why it might have done that to me?  Also setVisible worked right where it was (Ive always done setVisible at the top as that is the way my teacher taught me, is it that much different to set it in the end?)

Comment: 1- It worked because `setText` changes what is displayed. `setName` is used as a internal marker, mostly for GUI form editors, but sometimes other things (some layout managers use it). 2- Calling `setVisible` before the UI has been built can make the UI appear "empty" or only partially updated on some systems, we also recommend calling it last to avoid these issues...

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info on setVisible.  It turns out the reason why it was erroring was not that I wasnt using setName, but because I was using "" to blank out setText.  Turns out "" will cause the label to not show, yet " " will.  I guess "" is not a valid string?  My professor told us to use "" and I assumed "" would mean a null text.

Comment: Kind of, `""` is the same as using `null` (more or less), as it results in a size calculation equating to `0x0`, making it look like the label has not been displayed...

Comment: Ah, so does that mean by sorta nulling the text/name I was making the label not show up?

Comment: You we allowing the component's preferred size to become `0x0` (or close enough), which basically made it "look" like the button wasn't visible.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, since the text was null, the preferred size was null, so the labels were effectively too small to see.  Thank you for the info.

Comment: *"the preferred size was null"* - it is `0x0`, but yes, generally ;)

Comment: Ya I got what you meant generally :P.